# NSNumberformatter add extra zero

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter

I'm looking for a way to display "1" as "01", so basically everything below 10 should have a leading 0.

What would be the best way to do this?
I know I can just use a simple if structure to do this check, but this should be possible with NSNumberformatter right?

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25567534/1966109) that offers up to 3 solutions for a similar question tagged with `swift`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you just want an NSString, you can simply do this:

```
NSString *myNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", number];
```

The `%02d` is from C. %nd means there must be at least n characters in the string and if there are less, pad it with 0's. Here's an example:

```
NSString *example = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%010d", number];
```

If the `number` variable only was two digits long, it would be prefixed by eight zeroes. If it was 9 digits long, it would be prefixed by a single zero.

If you want to use NSNumberFormatter, you could do this:

```
NSNumberFormatter * numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setPaddingPosition:NSNumberFormatterPadBeforePrefix];
[numberFormatter setPaddingCharacter:@"0"];
[numberFormatter setMinimumIntegerDigits:10];
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:numberVariableHere];
```

----UPDATE------
I think this solves your problem:

```
[_minutes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", [[_minutes objectAtIndex:row] intValue]];
```

Comment: Thanks, that sure will help. But is it possible that getting the stringValue removes the 0 again?
I'm using this in a UIPickerView, but perhaps it's just better to do this in titleForRow

Comment: [_minutes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02@", [_minutes objectAtIndex:row]];

This just seems to return "1", "2"

Comment: A stringValue would not remove the 0 again because a string is a series of characters. In a string, the letter 'a' for example, is the same as a '0'. A string just stores characters, and both letters and numbers are characters.

Comment: @woutr_be See my update. I think I fixed your code that wasn't working.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, the updated code does work indeed, thanks a lot!

Comment: You don't need to call `setPaddingCharacter`. Just leave it to the `NSNumberFormatter`. :)

Answer (score 8):

## **FIXED for Swift 3**

```
let x = 999.1243
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1 // for float
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1 // for float
formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 10 // digits do want before decimal
formatter.paddingPosition = .beforePrefix
formatter.paddingCharacter = "0"

let s = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(floatLiteral: x))!
```

**OUTPUT**

"0000000999.1"

Comment: Thanks! Note that default paddingCharacter is "0", but you are correct, setting it safer.