# How to add `0` in before the value when the value length == 1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, split

I have the variable called `values = "2"`. Now when the value `length == 1` i need to add `0` at before the value.And if the value `length ==2` no need to do any thing.How can i add `0` at before.

And when i try to convert int to string.And when i get the last 6 digit Like :

```
Number = "123456789"
```

Here when i try to get last 5 digit value.Then its printing like :

```
[ "7"  "8" "9" ")"  """  ]
```

How to extract numbers alone..Here my code :

```
let Acc = info.TotalNo
  let U = "\(Acc)"
let AccountNos = String(U.characters.suffix(5))
let list = AccountNos.characters.map { String($0) }
```

Then its printing like this :

```
[ "7"  "8" "9" " closeBracket"  " double colon "  ]
```

But i want :

```
[ "5"  "6" "7" "8"  "9"  ]
```

I know 2 question is not allowed..But tis two making me to break more code..Please give me some solution..

Thanks

Comment: var newStr:String = str [which have value "0"] + [yourString] as you are able to get string count so try using that

Comment: Are you sure to let Acc = info.TotalNo getting number is perfect?

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. How is the value in `Number` related to the output with the closing parenthesis?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Leading zeros for Int in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25566581/leading-zeros-for-int-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
You are getting an optional so this code should run fine

```
if let Acc = info.TotalNo {
  let U = "\(Acc)"
  let AccountNos = String(U.characters.suffix(5))
  let list = AccountNos.characters.map { String($0) }
}
```

I made some changes in code

```
let number = 123456789

let Acc = "\(number)"  //let U = "\(Acc)"
let AccountNos = String(Acc.characters.suffix(5))
let list = AccountNos.characters.map { String($0) }

print(list)
```

I think problem with your solution is in this statement

```
let Acc = info.TotalNo
```

you are not getting the number

If you want last six digits

```
let number = "123456789"
let AccountNos = String(number.characters.suffix(6))
let list = AccountNos.characters.map { String($0) }

print(list)
```

Now to prefix 0 before number

```
let value = "2"
var newValue = ""

if value.characters.count == 1 {
    newValue = "0\(value)"
}

print(newValue)
```

Comment: My ` let U = "\(Acc)"` is printing `Optional("25578001")`.But my `let AccountNos = String(U.characters.suffix(5))`  is printing `001")`..This is my isseu now

Comment: try this: String(U!.characters.suffix(5))

Comment: Hi any solution for here ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45605670/google-analytics-ecommerce-value-is-not-updating-in-google-analytics-console

Comment: any  solution for here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667948/how-to-add-followed-text-to-uitextfield

Answer (score 3):

you can format your number like this:

```
let format = "%02d"

let smallNumber = 2
let largerNumber = 13

let formattedSmallNumber = String(format: format, smallNumber)
// "02"
let formattedLargerNumber = String(format: format, largerNumber)
// "13"
```

Comment: any  solution for here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667948/how-to-add-followed-text-to-uitextfield

Answer (score 1):

As for Your first question, there are two ways both works

```
Using NSMutableString:
var val: NSMutableString = "2"
if val.length == 1 {
  val.insert("0", at: 0)
}

Using String:
var val2 = "1"
if val2.characters.count == 1 {
   val2.insert("0", at: val2.startIndex)
}
```

For your second question

```
let number = "123456789"
let string = number.substring(from: number.index(number.startIndex, 
offsetBy: 4))
var list = Array(string.characters)
```

Comment: any  solution for here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667948/how-to-add-followed-text-to-uitextfield

Answer (score 0):

Here you go 
for first part use

```
if values.characters.count < 2 {
    values = "0\(values)"
}
```

for second part you can use

```
var number = "123456789"
let Acc = "\(number)"
let AccountNos = String(Acc.characters.suffix(5))
let list = AccountNos.characters.map { String($0) }
```

Comment: My ` let U = "\(Acc)"` is printing `Optional("25578001")`.But my `let AccountNos = String(U.characters.suffix(5))`  is printing `001")`

Comment: Any solution please

Comment: list is printing correctly for me. Might be number is coming out to be 001 for you.

Comment: any  solution for here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667948/how-to-add-followed-text-to-uitextfield

Answer (score 0):

1. Answer
   `var values = "2"
   let length = values.characters.count
   if length == 1 {
      values = "0" + values
   }`

And if want you to convert the string to Int or double 
    `let doubleVal = Double(values)`

Comment: any  solution for here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667948/how-to-add-followed-text-to-uitextfield

Answer (score 0):

**First Approach**

```
for myInt in 1...100 {
    print(String(format: "%02d", myInt))
}
```

**Second Approach** using ***arguments***

```
let string0 = String(format: "%02d", arguments: [0]) // returns "00"
let string1 = String(format: "%02d", arguments: [1]) // returns "01"
let string2 = String(format: "%02d", arguments: [10]) // returns "10"
let string3 = String(format: "%02d", arguments: [100]) // returns "100"
```

**Third Approach** using ***NumberFormatter***

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 2

let optionalString0 = formatter.string(from: 0) // returns Optional("00")
let optionalString1 = formatter.string(from: 1) // returns Optional("01")
let optionalString2 = formatter.string(from: 10) // returns Optional("10")
let optionalString3 = formatter.string(from: 100) // returns Optional("100")
```

Reference link 
[Leading zeros for Int in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25566581/leading-zeros-for-int-in-swift)

Comment: any  solution for here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667948/how-to-add-followed-text-to-uitextfield