# How to convert the each date components to particular date format in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I can obtain the individual date components as:

```
let dateString = String(dataModel.dateCompletedDay) + String(dataModel.dateCompletedMonth) + String(dataModel.dateCompletedYear)
print(dateString)
//2532016
```

Now how can i to convert it to DD/MM/YYYY format?

Comment: Use this `let dateString = String(dataModel.dateCompletedDay) + "/" + String(dataModel.dateCompletedMonth) + "/" + String(dataModel.dateCompletedYear)`

Comment: you want to need in Date or string formate?

Comment: StringFormat...

Comment: @jennysam see my comment

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava now the format should work as 25/03/2016? does you answer meet that??It should automatically append 0 in month and day if it is one digit.

Comment: @jennysam `dataModel.dateCompletedMonth` what will this return. Int?

Comment: every components are returning Int

Comment: @jennysam Leading zeros are not present in Int. `dataModel.dateCompletedMonth` probably returns 3 for 3rd month not 03. Please check since there is no point of writing extra code in your case.

Comment: @jennysam try this link for 2 digit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25566581/leading-zeros-for-int-in-swift

Comment: @jennysam try this for day and month let stringDate = String(format: "%02d", dataModel.dateCompletedMonth)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest to use `Calendar`, `DateComponents` and `DateFormatter` (Swift 3)

```
let components = DateComponents(year:dataModel.dateCompletedYear, month: dataModel.dateCompletedMonth, day: dataModel.dateCompletedDay)
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)!
let date = calendar.date(from: components)!
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
let dateString = formatter.string(from: date)
```

Additionally this is a simple solution which is supposed to work also in Swift 2

```
let dateString = String(format: "%02ld/%02ld/%ld", dataModel.dateCompletedDay, dataModel.dateCompletedMonth, dataModel.dateCompletedYear)
```

Comment: Can this be in swift 2 please?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Swift 2 anymore for a long time and it's highly recommended to update. Swift 4 is raring to go.