# Swift 4: modifying numbers in String

Tags: swift, string, string-interpolation

In my application i create multiple files and i would like them to have consecutive numbering as part of the name. For example *log_0001, log_0002*

I use string interpolation, so in code it looks like

```
fileName = "log_\(number)"
number = number + 1
```

However, if i keep `number` as just `Int`, i will have *log_1* instead of *log_0001*

I've only figured that i could check if `number` has 1/2/3/4 digits and add '000/00/0' manually.

Are there any String modifications allowing to put the required number of '0' to make it 4 symbols?

Answer (score 0):

"I've only figured that i could check if number has 1/2/3/4 digits and add '000/00/0' manually."

In this case try the following code: Save the digit length in a variable, for example digitLength.

```
if (digitLength == 1) { print("log_000") 
} else if (digitLength == 2) { print("log_00")
} else if (digitLength == 3) { print("log_0")
}
else { print("log_") }

print(number)
```

and then the variable.

Comment: Yikes, at least use a `switch`!

Comment: you could also try to convert the  Int in Swift to a String with leading zeros.

Comment: in this case read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25566581/leading-zeros-for-int-in-swift

Comment: And where does `digit` come from? The question is about a number starting with 1 and incrementing over time.

Comment: Hello @rmaddy, I have change the code, from digit to digitLength, for better understanding.

Comment: OK, then where does `digitLength` come from?

Comment: From the question. Read carefully. :)

Comment: I have read it, that's why I'm asking you. The code in the question is about a number. There is no code showing a digit length. For your answer to be useful, you should show how `digitLength` is calculated from `number`. Of course at this point you may as well delete your answer since the question has been closed as a duplicate.

Comment: He wrote "I've only figured that i could check if number has 1/2/3/4 digits and add '000/00/0' manually."