# How can I add a zero to the beginning of an answer that is less than 1.00 in swift xcode?

Tags: swift, number-formatting

My code below will output a value of £.88 when a small calculation is completed.

But I would like to output £0.88

Is this possible?

I've found a few solutions but none are working with my code.

Thanks for any help.

```
@IBAction func buttoncalc2(_ sender: Any) {
        total2.isHidden = false
        let fifthValue = Double(text5!.text!)
        let sixthValue = Double(text6!.text!)

        if fifthValue != nil && sixthValue != nil {

            let outputvalue2 = Double(((fifthValue! * sixthValue!)/1000)*0.5)
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.roundingMode = .up
            formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
            formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
            let string = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: outputvalue2)) ?? ""
            total2.text = "£ \(string)"

        }else{
            total2.text = nil
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Swift was built based on Objective-C, so searching for Objective-C answers as well as Swift answers can be very helpful. I think this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11131497/350538

Comment: @TinCan despite the fact that this answer can provide working solution, I think that thinking about result of formatter as about currency can be right approach.

Comment: Note that you can avoid force-unwrapping if you would use optional binding inside if statement: `if let fifthValue = fifthValue, let sixthValue = sixthValue {`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/29783546/2303865

Comment: I agree with @RobertDresler. Even if adding the minimumIntegerDigits like I had, somewhat opaquely, suggested would work, using a currency formatter is clearer about the intent of your code.

Comment: Way too many uses of `!` in your code. Consider learning how to properly and safely unwrap optionals when you get a chance.

Comment: Thanks for everyones input. I do know my code is a bit sloppy and needs tidying up so will look in to it a bit closer. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Different approach:

Make your formatter "currency formatter". It will automatically add currency symbol and this missing zero for you

```
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_UK")
```

```
let string = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: outputvalue2)) ?? ""
print(string) // £0.88
```

Comment: Thanks that tidies things up a bit.